# Values are blanks when returned from the API

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

The json values are blank when calling this code from the API:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ReportDesignerSetupController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public object GetReportDesignerModel([FromForm] string reportUrl)
        {
             return Ok(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>("{name: \"Seb\", age: 42, gender: \"M\"}"));
        }
    }
```

```
{
  "name": [],
  "age": [],
  "gender": []
}
```

Does anybody has any reason the value are blanks?

Thank you very much!

Reference:

I am debugging a project related to DevEXpress.

https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2019/12/03/reporting-for-blazor-how-to-use-document-viewer-and-report-designer-in-server-side-blazor-apps.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Newtonsoft.Json if you can.
Just tried this code locally and it works just fine

```
    [HttpGet("test")]
    public IActionResult GetReportDesignerModel([FromForm] string reportUrl)
    {
        return Ok(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{name: \"Seb\", age: 42, gender: \"M\"}"));
    }
```

From Postman

[image: from Postman]

Comment: Adding .AddNewtonsoftJson() fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How do you call your web api(url) from postman/insomnia .. etc ? It seems you are returning a data(GET) but your method is marked as `[HttpPost("[action]")]`. Could you edit the method as `HttpGet` and try?

Comment: Using insomnia, same thing with a post or a get, thanks for the suggestion.